# How to reference a file inside class library

Tags: c#, .net

I have this code in my asp.net app:

```
String appPath = HttpContext.Current.Request.MapPath(HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath);

String path = appPath + "\\Database\\SAMPLE.BIN";
```

I want to movie it to a class library, which then will be referenced by multiple projects.

The thing is that `HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath` is referencing the running app and not the class lib.

How do I put the `SAMPLE.BIN` inside the class lib, so that I don't have to duplicate it in all referencing projects?

EDIT:

At the end I need to be able to:

```
myobject.DatabasePath = appRoot + "\\Database\\SAMPLE.BIN";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 choices:

Either you pass the value as a parameter to your new library:

```
public class MyNewLibrary {
  private string _path { get; set; }

  public MyNewLibrary(string path)
  {
      this.path = path;
  }
}
```

or you import the `System.Web` reference and use the `HttpContext` at will.

Comment: Thanks, but if I import the System.Web, then I will have to have a copy "\\Database\\SAMPLE.BIN" in all referencing apps, right? My question is how to store the SAMPLE.BIN inside the class lib.

Comment: You are wanting to embed the resource into the compiled class lib?  You can use [embedded resources](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319292) for that.